# opengl -- setting up glad on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I followed [this](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html) tutorial to write a simple project using GLFW and glad but I don't know how to set up glad in my project. I am currently using Eclipse.

To be more precise, I am trying to ask how to correctly include glad in a project

Comment: I added glad.h to my include path but Idk where to put glad.c

Comment: The "duplicate answer" is ridiculous and too general to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the GLFW header. Also include the GLAD header BEFORE the GLFW header.

Comment: I think my headers are correctly included. However I still got an error saying 'undefined reference to GladGLLoader'. Do you know where to put glad.h and glad.c?

Comment: Have you included the GLAD source in your project?

Comment: I did but I think I was not including it in a right place??

Comment: Generate the GLAD loader using http://http://glad.dav1d.de/ Then copy the glad.h, glad.c, and khrplatform.h to a GLAD library folder in your src directory.

Comment: That's what I did before but it gave me a compile error when I include <glad/glad.h> in my main.cpp

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I am having the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @vmil, that link is dead.

Comment: two commands:
to install pull glad python stuff: pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/dav1dde/glad.git#egg=glad
to made a c inc/src file with the glad python stuff: python -m glad --generator=c --spec=gl --out-path yourgladfolderpath